# Error: A fatal error occurred while trying to verify jars. An exception has been thrown in class JarCertVerifier. (javaws and jnlp files)

Tags: java, java-web-start, java-ws

I'm trying to open a jnlp file, but I have the next error:

> selected jre: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java WARNING: package javax.jnlp
> not in java.desktop selected jre: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java WARNING:
> package javax.jnlp not in java.desktop java.util.zip.ZipException: zip
> END header not found  at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1607)  at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1497)     at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1504)     at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.(ZipFile.java:1308)  at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1271)     at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.(ZipFile.java:733)
> at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:850)
> at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:248)     at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:177)  at
> java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:350)  at
> java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:321)  at
> java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:274)  at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.JarFile.(JarFile.java:60)     at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.tools.JarCertVerifier.verifyJar(JarCertVerifier.java:275)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.tools.JarCertVerifier.verifyJars(JarCertVerifier.java:245)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.tools.JarCertVerifier.add(JarCertVerifier.java:211)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.initializeResources(JNLPClassLoader.java:732)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.(JNLPClassLoader.java:338)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.createInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:421)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:495)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:468)
> at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:814)
> at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:531)
> at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:945)
>
> java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found  at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1607)  at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1497)     at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1504)     at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.(ZipFile.java:1308)  at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1271)     at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.(ZipFile.java:733)
> at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:850)
> at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:248)     at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:177)  at
> java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:350)  at
> java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:321)  at
> java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:274)  at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.JarFile.(JarFile.java:60)     at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.tools.JarCertVerifier.verifyJar(JarCertVerifier.java:275)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.tools.JarCertVerifier.verifyJars(JarCertVerifier.java:245)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.tools.JarCertVerifier.add(JarCertVerifier.java:211)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.initializeResources(JNLPClassLoader.java:732)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.(JNLPClassLoader.java:338)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.createInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:421)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:495)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:468)
> at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:814)
> at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:531)
> at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:945)
>
> netx: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. (Fatal:
> Initialization Error: A fatal error occurred while trying to verify
> jars. An exception has been thrown in class JarCertVerifier. Being
> unable to read the cacerts or trusted.certs files could be a possible
> cause for this exception.: zip END header not found)
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error:
> Could not initialize application. The application has not been
> initialized, for more information execute javaws from the command
> line.     at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:822)    at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:531)    at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:945) Caused
> by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error:
> A fatal error occurred while trying to verify jars. An exception has
> been thrown in class JarCertVerifier. Being unable to read the cacerts
> or trusted.certs files could be a possible cause for this exception.:
> zip END header not found  at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.initializeResources(JNLPClassLoader.java:739)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.(JNLPClassLoader.java:338)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.createInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:421)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:495)
> at
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:468)
> at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:814)
> ... 2 more

My PC is running under Linux Mint 20.
The ouput of my java version:

```
java --version 
openjdk 11.0.16 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Doing `javaws --viewer` I have import my CA Certificate